# Reduced form of an ideal intersection.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Consider the intersection of ideals

$$ I =(y^2 - x^3 - x^2)\cap (x) \cap (y) \subset k[x,y] $$
with $k$ a field.

Is true that $I = ((y^2 - x^3 - x^2)xy)$?, If the answer is false, then what is a reduce form for $I$?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$k[x,y]$ is a U.F.D. and $x$, $y$ and $y^2-x^3-x^2$ are distinct irreducible elements in this ring.

Comment: Thanks! I doubted, because I'm not sure if $k[x,y]$ was a UFD. Where Can I find the proof of this ? (k[x,y] is UFD)

Comment: Bourbaki, *Commutative Algebra*, ch. VII: *Divisors*, §3, no 5, Theorem 2.